# Using variable in SQL LIKE statement

Tags: sql-server

I've got a sproc (MSSQL 2k5) that will take a variable for a LIKE claus like so:

```
DECLARE @SearchLetter2 char(1)
SET @SearchLetter = 't'
SET @SearchLetter2 = @SearchLetter + '%'
SELECT *
    FROM BrandNames 
    WHERE [Name] LIKE @SearchLetter2 and IsVisible = 1 
    --WHERE [Name] LIKE 't%' and IsVisible = 1 
    ORDER BY [Name]
```

Unfortunately, the line currently running throws a syntax error, while the commented where clause runs just fine.  Can anyone help me get the un-commented line working?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Joel is it that @SearchLetter hasn't been declared yet?  Also the length of @SearchLetter2 isn't long enough for 't%'.  Try a varchar of a longer length.

Answer (score 115):

If you are using a Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE <Name>
(
    @PartialName VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)

SELECT Name 
    FROM <table>
    WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @PartialName + '%'
```

Answer (score 22):

As Andrew Brower says, but adding a trim

```
ALTER PROCEDURE <Name>
(
    @PartialName VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)

SELECT Name 
    FROM <table>
    WHERE Name LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@PartialName)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 9):

But in my opinion one important thing.

The "char(number)" it's lenght of variable.

If we've got table with "Names" like for example [Test1..Test200] and we declare char(5) in SELECT like:

```
DECLARE @variable char(5)
SET @variable = 'Test1%'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name like @variable
```

the result will be only - "Test1"! (char(5) - 5 chars in lenght; Test11 is 6 )

The rest of potential interested data like [Test11..Test200] will not be returned in the result.

It's ok if we want to limit the SELECT by this way. 
But if it's not intentional way of doing it could return incorrect results from planned
( Like "all Names begining with Test1..." ).

In my opinion if we don't know the precise lenght of a SELECTed value, a better solution could be something like this one:

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(max)
SET @variable = 'Test1%'
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE variable1 like @variable
```

This returns (Test1 but also Test11..Test19 and Test100..Test199).

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer, in my opinion.  putting the "%" in the variable value works, and makes the result as simple as "WHERE ... like @variable "

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on the Northwind sample DB, note that SearchLetter has 2 characters to it and SearchLetter also has to be declared for this to run:

```
declare @SearchLetter2 char(2)
declare @SearchLetter char(1)
Set @SearchLetter = 'A'
Set @SearchLetter2 = @SearchLetter+'%'
select * from Customers where ContactName like @SearchLetter2 and Region='WY'
```

Answer (score 4):

DECLARE @SearchLetter2 char(1)

Set this to a longer char.

Answer (score 3):

We can write directly too...

```
DECLARE @SearchLetter CHAR(1) 

SET @SearchLetter = 'A' 

SELECT * 
FROM   CUSTOMERS 
WHERE  CONTACTNAME LIKE @SearchLetter + '%' 
       AND REGION = 'WY'
```

or the following way as well if we have to append all the search characters then,

```
DECLARE @SearchLetter CHAR(1) 

SET @SearchLetter = 'A' + '%' 

SELECT * 
FROM   CUSTOMERS 
WHERE  CONTACTNAME LIKE @SearchLetter 
       AND REGION = 'WY'
```

Both these will work

Answer (score 2):

I had also problem using local variables in LIKE.
Important is to know: **how long is variable**.
Below, **ORDER_NO** is **50** characters long, so You can not use: *LIKE @ORDER_NO*, because in the end will be spaces.
You need to trim right side of the variable first.
Like this:

```
DECLARE @ORDER_NO char(50)
SELECT @ORDER_NO = 'OR/201910/0012%'

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE ord_no LIKE RTRIM(@ORDER_NO)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I needed to use just a small piece of a URL saved in my database where the front and ends were irrelevant.

I first attempted to use:

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(250) = %x%;
SELECT * FROM tblone WHERE column1 LIKE '@variable'
```

However, this returned the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

My working query was formatted:

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(1000) = x;
SELECT * FROM tblone WHERE column1 LIKE '%'+@variable+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be as simple as `LIKE '%%[%3]%%'` being `[%3]` the input variable.

This works for me with SAP B1 9.1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CONCAT()` as follows:

```
SET @variable='some_value';                                                        
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE (SELECT CONCAT('%',@variable,'%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but still useful and applicable. This type of issue is primarily caused due to type conversion (especially true if the variable is *not* of character type (e.g. varchar).

The newer versions of SQL Server (2019 & 2022) do better auto-casting / auto-type-conversion, you are less likely to see this issue in them.

Having said above, to be on the safe side (as others mentioned) use Trim() to avoid any issue that may be caused due to blank spaces.

**Trim and Contact Combined:**

I have written another example for ease of understanding that use Trim() and Contact() functions:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(256) = 'your_database_to_find';
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(@var),'%');
```

OR just:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name LIKE '%'+TRIM(@var)+'%'
```

Note: Trim() was introduced in SQL Server 2017, for older versions use LTRIM() and RTRIM().

HTH.