# SQL passing a value in Like Command

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using variable in SQL LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement)

I want it to be like this and its ok..

```
Declare @modCode varchar(3)
SET @modCOde = 'SOR';

Select dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode, Num) 
From Doc_SalesOrder 
Where Num not LIKE @modCOde
```

but I want to use it like this.

```
Declare @modCode varchar(3)
SET @modCOde = 'SOR';

Select dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode, Num) 
From Doc_SalesOrder 
Where Num not LIKE %@modCOde%
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Please review question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
DECLARE @modCode VARCHAR(3)
SET @modCOde = 'SOR';

SELECT dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode, Num) 
FROM Doc_SalesOrder 
WHERE Num NOT LIKE '%' + @modCOde + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @modCode varchar(5)
SET @modCOde = '%SOR%';
SELECT dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode,Num) 
      FROM Doc_SalesOrder 
      WHERE Num not LIKE @modCOde
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   DECLARE @modCode VARCHAR(3)
    SET @modCOde = 'SOR';

    SELECT dbo.ApplyModuleCode(@modCode, Num) FROM Doc_SalesOrder WHERE
 Num NOT LIKE '%' + @modCOde + '%'
```