# SQL Server - Where Like statement with variable returning no results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with dates formatted as strings in the following manner YYYY-MM-DD.
The data contains several years worth of data and I would like to pull just the current year using the following query:

```
Declare @currentYear VARCHAR(5)
Select @currentYear = year(getdate())

select *
from tablename
where datefixed like @currentYear
```

The query above is not returning any results. 
I've tried following the methodology outlined in this thread: [Using variable in SQL LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement)

I'm missing something, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: You are trying to use like meant for strings on a date try use between startdate and endDate

Comment: We should stop answering questions where OP is asking for help to fix their messy database design on query level. Maybe then they start to use the correct type in the first place. Normally the query would be simple: `WHERE YEAR(datefixed) = YEAR(GETDATE())`

Comment: Thank you @TimSchmelter. Our new design uses yyyymmdd which allows the use of between and easy like statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the trailing wildcard `%`:

```
select *
from tablename
where datefixed like @currentYear + '%'
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. That seems to have pulled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
Declare @currentYear int
Select @currentYear = year(getdate())

select *
from tablename
where year(convert(datetime,replace(datefixed,'-',''))) = @currentYear
```

If you want to use like operator, you must to ensure datefixed is a string type (varchar, char etc..) and add a wildcard (%)

Comment: He stores strings not datetimes

Comment: Might throw exception because of format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Perfect @MelgoV, this works as well. We are currently using yyyymmdd which is a lot easier to work with.