# SQL How to compare if a variable is the same as a value in a database column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The problem I have is the following:

I work with a ticket system that uses plugins to realize workflows. 
In this case I use SQL to presort incoming emails.
The SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT Count(Case when {MSG_CC_002_DeviceReg_MailBody} LIKE '%You have received an invoice from%' Then 1 END);
```

What I want to do now is instead of using LIKE and then a certain phrase like above, I want to compare this to a column in a database table that contains all necessary phrases.

The table has only two columns, phraseID and phrase.
{MSG_CC_002_DeviceReg_MailBody} is the variable that needs to compared against the values of the column.
So if the variable matches with an entry in the column it should just return 1.

[Edit:]
This is just one of the things I want to use this for, I also have a variable {MSG_CC_002_DeviceReg_MailSender} that will provide the email address that I want to compare to a similar table that contains email addresses.

Is this possible?
If so - how?

Comment: So I'm clear, you want to compare the `MailBody` to every value in the `Phrase` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be dog-slow if you have a lot of phrases or email addresses, but it'll give you what you want.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RetValue
FROM PhraseTable 
WHERE {MSG_CC_002_DeviceReg_MailBody} LIKE '%' + phrase + '%';
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you could accept the answer (click the grey check mark to the left), I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` or a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from othertable ot
              where {MSG_CC_002_DeviceReg_MailBody} LIKE '%' + ot.phrase + '%' 
             ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you can achieve this with using dynamic query. Basically you need to construct your query as a string then execute it.

You can find examples and more information about dynamic query within the following link;

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: To extend the answer of Serdar, you can even let a Stored-Procedure create the dynamic SQL. Thus all you have to do is provide the procedure a variable and it will return the answer. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement