# How To use variable in sql like statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my sql statement

```
SELECT m.id 
FROM (SELECT id, plu FROM product) t 
   join position m ON m.plu_id LIKE '%' + @t.plu
```

but got such error **operator does not exist: @ character varying**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement)
did not help

Comment: What is this variable? Where is `@t` declared? What is it? What is `@t.plu`?

Comment: The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`. The `+` is to add numbers. And `@` is invalid in an identifier in SQL as well.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: the sub-select is completely useless. You can simplify that to `select .. from product t join position m ...`

Comment: @underscore_d - I want to compare plu from position and plu from product

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks, your comment helped. You can post an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator in Postgres -- and in SQL in general -- is addition of numbers.  That SQL Server extends this definition to include string concatenation is bespoke syntax for that database (and Sybase).

Use the correct candidate operator:

```
ON m.plu_id LIKE '%@' || t.plu
```

I assume that the `@` is really a constant character that should be part of the pattern.