# LIKE clause in T-SQL statement does not return value if compared with a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find all the backup tables I have just created with another script.

```
declare @bkup_tbls varchar(20) = '''%_' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112  ))) + ''''

select @bkup_tbls  --'%_20210703' -- (1 row(s) affected)

select * 
from sys.objects 
where name like @bkup_tbls 
  and type = 'U' --(0 row(s) affected)
```

I have verified the tables exist in the `sys.objects` catalog view by the same value generated by the above declared variable.

```
select * 
from sys.objects 
where name like '%_20210703' 
  and type = 'U'  --(3 row(s) affected)
```

Am I missing anything? Any help would be much appreciated.

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM)

Found related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement/16406449), but that didn't help either

Comment: What do you mean "backup table"?  Are these tables that you manually created?

Comment: I have used this naming convention  '_TodaysDate' to backup some non-dbo tables before dropping them. Now I am going to recreate them but before I start execution I want to make sure they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out the backup variable value, you will see that it has single quotes:

```
'%_20210703'
```

Those single quotes are *part of the string*, not delimiters.  You don't want them.

What you really want is:

```
declare @bkup_tbls varchar(20) = '%_' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112  )))
```

which produces the string:

```
%_20210703
```

I suspect that you are confusing parameter substitution with dynamic SQL, which is why you think the delimiting single quotes are necessary.