# How can I use LIKE with @value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I don't know if this question has been asked before. I searched but I couldn't find the answer.

In short, I want to do something in MsSQL like:

```sql
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(2000) = 'Joe and Bill and Michael are my friends'   
SELECT * FROM my_friends WHERE my_friends.name LIKE %@VALUE%
```

I want to get records from my_friends table which "name" column is in `@VALUE` string. For this case, Joe, Bill and Michael.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here, as MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Please [edit] your post to tag correctly.

Comment: Hint, the wildcards should be wrapping column, not the variable, in the above scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variable in SQL LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390362/using-variable-in-sql-like-statement)

Comment: Does it have to be case sensitive?

Comment: @GSerg No, because the question you linked is about searching a value in a column of a table. But mine is searching the column of a table in value.

Comment: @PhilCoulson No, in my real case the column is all capital

Comment: @AhmetÇöl I don't see how `a like '%' + b + '%'` is an answer while `b like '%' + a + '%'` isn't. The meat of your question is that you attempted `%@VALUE%` and you should have attempted `'%' + @VALUE + '%'`, which the duplicate resolves in the exactly same way as the now accepted answer here.

Comment: @GSerg Already `value like '%' + column '%'` is the answer. But `column like '%' + value + '%'` isn't. I don't know the difference.

Comment: @AhmetÇöl `like` doesn't work like an equality operator (=). The pattern goes on the right side and the value being compared against it goes on the left (unless both are exactly the same values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your name is meant to be a substring of your variable, you want

```
WHERE @VALUE like '%'+name+'%'
```

You could also use `charindex` if you want case sensitive matches

```
WHERE charindex(names,@VALUE)>0
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot. The first one worked.